# Recyclerview Layout below a NestedScollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

In my application I have a NestedScrollView which holds a TextView. I want to add A RecyclerView under the NestedScrollView but it doesn't show anything.
Here is my Layout xml file

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.trueblueoperator.samplescrolling.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>
<include layout="@layout/recyclerview_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_scrolling.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.trueblueoperator.swachhapp.StoryDetailFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_story_detail">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/story_detail_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="@string/large_text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

recyclerview_content.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Here is my Fragment which holds the Recyclerview with StaggeredviewLayout manager.

```
public class FragmentAllStory extends Fragment  implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener{

//Creating a List of superheroes
private List<AllComments> allcommentList;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

private Boolean orientation = true;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
//The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
private int requestCount = 1;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestCount = 1;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_content, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1));
    }
    else {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, 1));
    }
    allcommentList = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    fetchData();//data is fetched and stored in the ArrayList
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
    adapter = new AllCommentsAdapter(allcommentList, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    //JsonArrayRequest of volley
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                    parseData(response);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}

//This method will get data from the web api
private void fetchData() {
    //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
    //Incrementing the request counter
    requestCount++;
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the superhero object
        Allcomments allcomment = new Allcomments();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the superhero object
            allcomment.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            allcomment.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
            allcomment.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        allcommentList.add(allcomment);

    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//This method would check that the recyclerview scroll has reached the bottom or not
private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    int[] info = new int[3];
    if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
        ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(info);
        Log.d("info", "" + info[0] + " " + info[1]);
        if (info[0] == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1 || info[1] == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1 || info[2] == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    //Ifscrolled at last then
    if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
        //Calling the method getdata again
        fetchData();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what is happening in fetchData()?

Comment: The collapsingToolbarLayout only works with one scrollView below.
Maybe you should try to use only the recyclerView and add the text as a header to it instead of one nestedScrollView and one RecyclerView.

Comment: @inner_class7 I have edited the code with fetchData()

Comment: you have not provided and id for your recycler view

Comment: @Oliver I have the large content in my TextView, so i think it will not be good to put inside the header because header is stuck at the topso it will not allow the recyclerview to scroll upside on fullwindow

Comment: @inner_class7 that was left by mistake but still I am not able to see the Recyclerview content

Comment: With header i just meant you should put the Text view as first element into the list.

Comment: @YogeshYadav i faced a very similar issue like you did. Follow Oliver's solution. He's right in this scenario